# How do you check for the type of variable in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In Elixir how do you check for type such as in Python:

```
>>> a = "test"
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> b =10
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
```

I read in Elixir there are type checkers such as 'is_bitstring', 'is_float', 'is_list', 'is_map' etc, but what if you have no idea what the type could be ?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There's no direct way to get the type of a variable in Elixir/Erlang.

You usually want to know the type of a variable in order to act accordingly; you can use the `is_*` functions in order to act based on the type of a variable.

Learn You Some Erlang has [a nice chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/types-or-lack-thereof) about typing in Erlang (and thus in Elixir).

The most idiomatic way to use the `is_*` family of functions would probably be to use them in pattern matches:

```
def my_fun(arg) when is_map(arg), do: ...
def my_fun(arg) when is_list(arg), do: ...
def my_fun(arg) when is_integer(arg), do: ...
# ...and so on
```

Comment: Does Erlang/Elixir really have no stored type information? Do I really need to create a whole new wrapper over existing types for the language to be usable? O.o

Comment: @Dmitry what do you mean by usable? Can I see a concrete example where you would use the result of something like `typeof(variable)`?

Comment: When a program leaves compile time and enters runtime, all information about what some object is is lost. When I want to inspect information of a running program, the only way to know what is going on is by inspecting things which are exposed via a network of maps. if the type information is not available, and I want to inspect the type, it costs much more to analyze the object to obtain its' type than if the type was already exposed. typeof allows us to analyze the running system and extend it at runtime in a way that allows typechecking and polymorphism.

Comment: To be more specific; the most useful use of typeof is the ability to directly map a hash table of [type string, function] onto list of unknowns.

For example; IO.puts can't be mapped over `foo = [1, "hello", [1, 2, 3]]`, with code `Enum.map(foo, fn(x) -> IO.puts x end)` because [1,2, 3] will be read as characters(why erlang!!?), and will show you a bunch of smily faces(try it!). so we are forced to use inspect even though inspect is only needed if it's a list, otherwise most of the time we don't need it. typeof lets us turn if statements(O(n)) into dictionary lookups(O(1)).

Comment: @Dmitry for that type of use Elixir protocols would be useful. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html You could implement your own `Printable` protocol which wraps and changes the behaviour of printing e.g. lists of integers. Just make sure you don't use it with Erlang code—or you'll be scratching your head wondering why instead of messages you're seeing lists of integers.

Comment: concrete example: testing if one date is greater than the other. It's failing. One possible cause is that the dates are actually strings which would change the behavior significantly in some cases. I want to figure out if the dates are actually strings or not.

Comment: @jaydel two years later, but someone else might end up here. The way to do that is probably like: def compare_dates(dt_a, dt_b) when is_string(dt_a) or is_string(dt_b) do ... end, for the case when either is a string.

Answer (score 218):

Starting in elixir 1.2 there is an `i` command in iex that will list the type and more of any Elixir variable.

```
iex> foo = "a string" 
iex> i foo 
Term
 "a string"
Data type
 BitString
Byte size
 8
Description
 This is a string: a UTF-8 encoded binary. It's printed surrounded by
 "double quotes" because all UTF-8 encoded codepoints in it are        printable.
Raw representation
  <<97, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103>>
Reference modules
  String, :binary
```

If you look in the code for the `i` command you'll see that this is implemented via a Protocol.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/iex/lib/iex/info.ex

If you want to implement a function for any Data type in Elixir, the way to do that is to define a Protocol and implementation of the Protocol for all the data types you want the function to work on. Unfortunately, you can't use a Protocol function in guards. However, a simple "type" protocol would be very straightforward to implement.

Comment: in 2019 this returns an error `undefined function i/1` - same for info/1

Comment: This still works in Elixir 1.8.1. You must have a very old version of elixir installed.

Comment: @krivar @fred-the-magic-wonder-dog you are both correct :).  `&i/1` is a function on `IEx.Helpers`.  If you put `&IEx.Helpers.i/1` into your vanilla Elixir it, you'll generate a `CompileError` unless you've included `:iex` as application in your `mix.exs`.

Answer (score 65):

Also for debugging purposes, if you're not in iex, you can call it directly:

```
IEx.Info.info(5)
=> ["Data type": "Integer", "Reference modules": "Integer"]
```

Comment: If you want to see it in your log add
IO.inspect (IEx.Info.info(5))

Comment: You can call this directly if you are or aren't in IEx. In fact this is not the same as calling `i/1` since `i/1` only prints information, but this one let's you capture the result.

Answer (score 38):

I'll just leave this here for the sake of somebody hopefully figuring out an actually sane version. At the moment there are no good answers to this coming up on google...

```ex
defmodule Util do
    def typeof(a) do
        cond do
            is_float(a)    -> "float"
            is_number(a)   -> "number"
            is_atom(a)     -> "atom"
            is_boolean(a)  -> "boolean"
            is_binary(a)   -> "binary"
            is_function(a) -> "function"
            is_list(a)     -> "list"
            is_tuple(a)    -> "tuple"
            true           -> "idunno"
        end    
    end
end
```

For the sake of completeness, test cases:

```ex
cases = [
    1.337, 
    1337, 
    :'1337', 
    true, 
    <<1, 3, 3, 7>>, 
    (fn(x) -> x end), 
    {1, 3, 3, 7}
]

Enum.each cases, fn(case) -> 
    IO.puts (inspect case) <> " is a " <> (Util.typeof case)
end
```

Here's a solution with protocols; I am not sure if they are faster(I sure hope they are not doing a loop over all types), but it is pretty ugly(and fragile; if they add or remove a basic type or rename, it will break it).

```ex
defprotocol Typeable, do: def typeof(a)
defimpl Typeable, for: Atom, do: def typeof(_), do: "Atom"
defimpl Typeable, for: BitString, do: def typeof(_), do: "BitString"
defimpl Typeable, for: Float, do: def typeof(_), do: "Float"
defimpl Typeable, for: Function, do: def typeof(_), do: "Function"
defimpl Typeable, for: Integer, do: def typeof(_), do: "Integer"
defimpl Typeable, for: List, do: def typeof(_), do: "List"
defimpl Typeable, for: Map, do: def typeof(_), do: "Map"
defimpl Typeable, for: PID, do: def typeof(_), do: "PID"
defimpl Typeable, for: Port, do: def typeof(_), do: "Port"
defimpl Typeable, for: Reference, do: def typeof(_), do: "Reference"
defimpl Typeable, for: Tuple, do: def typeof(_), do: "Tuple"

IO.puts Typeable.typeof "Hi"
IO.puts Typeable.typeof :ok
```

Comment: If you really want a "type" checker, you easily build one using the tools in the philosopher's stone org. https://github.com/philosophers-stone. Phenetic is still in early days, but it can do this and a lot more.

Comment: easily bind myself to an external dependency? how is that going to improve my ability to share code with friends? This is a road to 2 problems.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @aks; I can actually go back to 4 spaces now ^_^

Comment: In Elixir `self` is the current process `PID`, this could be confusing.

Comment: @mrroot5 As far as I am aware `self` is not a keyword in elixir and you are refering to `self/1` which is allowed to be shadowed for local variables/parameters named `self` without any legitimate issues where `self/1` is not used. That said I changed `self` to `a`, I am tempted to replace `a` with `_` in final version but I do not remember Elixir enough to know if it is correct to do so(it seems to work though).

Answer (score 29):

Another approach is to use pattern matching.  Say you're using Timex, which uses a `%DateTime{}` struct, and you want to see if an element is one.  You can find a match using pattern matching in the method.

```
def datetime?(%DateTime{}) do
  true
end

def datetime?(_) do
  false
end
```

Comment: or, as the accepted answer remarked but did not stress: »You usually want to know the type of a variable in order to act accordingly«.  in Elixir you act accordingly by pattern matching, not by `switch` / `case`.

Answer (score 20):

I just paste the code from https://elixirforum.com/t/just-created-a-typeof-module/2583/5 :)

```ex
defmodule Util do
  types = ~w[function nil integer binary bitstring list map float atom tuple pid port reference]
  for type <- types do
    def typeof(x) when unquote(:"is_#{type}")(x), do: unquote(type)
  end
end
```

Comment: Clever use of quote! The more I see Elixir code the more it reminds me of Perl; that ~w construct looks very similar to qw//. I wonder if Perl has some clever mechanism to simulate Lisplike quote.

Comment: I wonder how quote works; can it be emulated using a regular expression preprocessor, or does it require a parser walk through the whole code to do macro expansion.

Answer (score 3):

## [`Useful.typeof/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/useful/Useful.html#typeof/1)

Inspired by this thread we added `typeof/1` to our library of `Useful` functions. 
 Does exactly what you expect.

Add it to your `deps` in `mix.exs`:

```
def deps do
  [
    {:useful, "~> 0.4.0"}
  ]
end
```

Usage:

```
iex> pi = 3.14159
iex> Useful.typeof(pi)
"float"

iex> fun = fn (a, b) -> a + b end
iex> Useful.typeof(fun)
"function"

iex> Useful.typeof(&Useful.typeof/1)
"function"

iex> int = 42
iex> Useful.typeof(int)
"integer"

iex> list = [1,2,3,4]
iex> Useful.typeof(list)
"list"
```

**Docs**: https://hexdocs.pm/useful/Useful.html#typeof/1 
As always, feedback/contributions/improvements very much welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IEx.Info.info` in iex and in your code. The result is a list of tuples, so the actual type information, which is contained as a string, needs some unpacking:

**IEx example**

```
iex(1)> "abc" |> IEx.Info.info |> hd |> elem(1)
"BitString"
```

**In your code**

```
def datatype(myvar) do
  myvar |> IEx.Info.info |> hd |> elem(1)
end

var1 = {1,2,3}
IO.puts(datatype(var1)) # will print the string "Tuple"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the implementation [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/iex/lib/iex/info.ex), you can pattern match against the tuple returned by `IEx.Info.info/1`:

```
defmodule Type do
  def of(x) do
    [{_, type} | _] = IEx.Info.info(x)

    type
  end
end

Type.of(1) # "Integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a situation need to check the parameter need to be certain type. Maybe can active a better way.

Like this:

```
@required [{"body", "binary"},{"fee", "integer"}, ...]
defp match_desire?({value, type}) do
  apply(Kernel, :"is_#{type}", [value])
end
```

Usage:

```
Enum.map(@required, &(match_desire?/1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python type using an Elixir Protocol

An approximation with a module implementation is @Dimitry answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777498/3377046).

#### Protocol source code

The code is big for an answer so I created a github gist. [Protocol implementation](https://gist.github.com/mrroot5/5da60f340a116c77dbb621538153b5d5).

I am a noob on testing and Elixir so any improvements are really appreciated.

### Docs

- [Elixir protocol tutorial](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html).
- [Elixir protocol docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html).

Answer (score -1):

Just because nobody has mentioned it

`IO.inspect/1`

Outputs to console the object ... its almost equiv to JSON.stringify

Very helpful when you just cannot for the life of you figure out what an object looks like in a test.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, not even close