# Handling Errors - Elixir

Tags: exception, error-handling, elixir

I have a simple function like this:

```
  def currencyConverter({ from, to, amount }) when is_float(amount) do
    result = exchangeConversion({ from, to, amount })
    exchangeResult = resultParser(result)
    exchangeResult
  end
```

I want to guarantee that from and to are strings and amount are float, and if not, display send a customize error message instead erlang error
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: you can use `is_float(amount)` etc - see https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#booleans

Comment: _Sidenote:_ **never ever use `float` type for currency representation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make two functions with same name and arity, one with guards and one without

```
def currencyConverter({from, to, amount}) when is_float(amount) and is_bitstring(to) and is_bitstring(from) do
  result = exchangeConversion({ from, to, amount })
  exchangeResult = resultParser(result)
  exchangeResult
end
def currencyConverter(_), do: raise "Custom error msg"
```

If you want to check the input type, you will need to create a function to do it because elixir does not have a global one.

```
def currencyConverter({from, to, amount}) when is_float(amount) and is_bitstring(to) and is_binary(from) do
  result = exchangeConversion({ from, to, amount })
  exchangeResult = resultParser(result)
  exchangeResult
end
def currencyConverter({from, to, amount}) do
 raise """
   You called currencyConverter/1 with the following invalid variable types:
   'from' is type #{typeof(from)}, need to be bitstring
   'to' is type #{typeof(to)}, need to be bitstring
   'amount' is type #{typeof(amount)}, need to be float
 """
end

def typeof(self) do
        cond do
            is_float(self)    -> "float"
            is_number(self)   -> "number"
            is_atom(self)     -> "atom"
            is_boolean(self)  -> "boolean"
            is_bitstring(self)-> "bitstring"
            is_binary(self)   -> "binary"
            is_function(self) -> "function"
            is_list(self)     -> "list"
            is_tuple(self)    -> "tuple"
            true              -> "ni l'un ni l'autre"
        end    
end
```

(typeof/1 function is based on this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777498/10998856)

Comment: I think you should use `is_binary` instead of `is_bitstring`.

Comment: Nice! But using this, can I know which input was invalid to custom the message?

Comment: @zwippie depends on the use case. 'foo' is binary but not bitstring. "foo" is binary and bitstring.

Comment: @RafaelPolonio just edited the post with your answer